# Material UI date picker behaving differently on mobile device

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI datepicker in a React project. I've created a calendar + time selection (code below). For some reason when I test this on Chrome desktop using the device toolbar to emulate iphone 8 it works fine, but when I go to the site on my actual iphone 8, the UI is broken (images below). Any thoughts?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import moment from 'moment';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
            padding: 0,
        },
    },
    picker: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
            flexDirection: 'column',
        },
    },
    timeContainer: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginLeft: 0,
            marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
        },
    },
    timeButton: { width: 226, height: 50 },
}));

export default function Timesgrid(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [selectedDate, setSeletedDate] = useState(moment());

    const disableDay = date => {
        const formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        return formattedDate in props.availability &&
            props.availability[formattedDate].length > 0
            ? false
            : true;
    };

    const handleDateChange = date => {
        setSeletedDate(moment(date));
    };

    const renderTimes = () => {
        const dateStr = moment(selectedDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        const availability = props.availability[dateStr];
        return availability && availability.length ? (
            <div className={classes.timeContainer}>
                {availability.map((time, i) => (
                    <Button
                        style={{ marginTop: i === 0 ? 0 : 10 }}
                        key={time}
                        className={classes.timeButton}
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={() => props.onDatetimeSelected(moment(time))}
                    >
                        <b>{moment(time).format('LT')}</b>
                    </Button>
                ))}
            </div>
        ) : (
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.timeContainer}>
                No availability
            </Typography>
        );
    };
    const renderPicker = () => {
        return (
            <div className={classes.picker}>
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    <DatePicker
                        disablePast
                        shouldDisableDate={disableDay}
                        variant="static"
                        defaultValue={selectedDate}
                        value={selectedDate}
                        onChange={handleDateChange}
                    />
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                {renderTimes()}
            </div>
        );
    };

    return <div className={classes.root}>{renderPicker()}</div>;
}

Timesgrid.propTypes = {
    availability: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    onDatetimeSelected: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

[image: On the Chrome iphone8 emulator]

[image: On my iphone8]

Comment: Chromes devtool emulators do not simulate the actual libraries used by the native devices. It doesn't even do a great job verifying the responsive design of your UI. Specifically, for certain input types iphone/android uses the devices native libraries to retrieve that information by default. That is how your keyboard is able to change between text, tel, number... etc.

Comment: I just realized your using a third-party material-ui library for your datepicker that specifically targets native applications. If you want to increase your workflow speed and be able to test I'd recommend using an emulator. You then would simply open your development port to the device to access it directly. That's really the only way to test native features in real time that I know of. If targeting iphone you'll need xcode and mac osx unfortunately.

Comment: That's helpful I didn't think of doing that. I've accessed it on the device simulator through Xcode, but I still don't know what the issue is or how I should best debug it.

Comment: I can only speculate but, I believe it's a height issue and since your using flexbox it's causing the screen to squish. In the chrome devtools version it looks like scrolling is allowed where the native screen is not allowing scrolling. So I would see if there are some settings in that third party library that enables scrolling.

Comment: You could try putting it in a Grid with a fixed height or height 100% and overflow: "scroll" or a style e.g. style={{ overflow: "scroll", height: "100%"}

Comment: Adding `overflowY: 'scroll', height: '100%'` to the `picker` style worked. Feel free to add that as answer and i'll accept..thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question as we discussed in comments was to add the following CSS styling.

```
overflow: scroll
height: 100%
```

Justification:

The reason I suggested this solution was due to the comparisons in your images. The popup screen for the component was mushed together on the native browser popup but, not on the Chrome DevTools popup. This indicated that the native browser container was not allowing for overflow to occur.

Setting the height of the component to 100% ensures that it takes up the full height of it's container and allowing overflow ensures that if your component is greater than 100% of the containers height that it will render as shown in the devtools view.

Furthermore, In your reply you said your solution was

```
overflowY: scroll, 
height: 100%
```

and overflow: scroll allows for overflow on both axes. Since the x-axis doesn't require overflow, this is a better solution.

Glad to see it worked.